# Vue panzoom container

Tags: vue.js, zooming, pan, panzoom

I would like to use this plug in to zoom and pan around a number of other components but am struggling to work out the best way to implement

https://github.com/timmywil/panzoom
It looks like a good library to use

I have only just started playing but my assumption was to make a basic component

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <div style="overflow: hidden">
      <div id="panzoom-element">
        <slot />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Panzoom from '@panzoom/panzoom'

export default {
  props: {
    options: { type: Object, default: () => {} },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.panzoom = Panzoom(document.getElementById('panzoom-element'), {
      maxScale: 5,
    })
  },
  methods: {},
}
</script>
```

I then in my Home.vue (view) to wrap the zoom component around the others

```
 <PanzoomLayer>
            <NodesLayer />
            <TipsLayer />
            <ConnectionsLayer />
</PanzoomLayer>
```

This didnt seem to do anything :)
Can someone point me in the right direction please ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It works good for me:

```
<template>
      <div ref="panzoomElement">
         <slot />
      </div>
</template>

mounted() {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
            this.panzoom = Panzoom(this.$refs.panzoomElement, {
                maxScale: 5,
            });
        });
    },
```